# React functional component does not handle event

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have storybook components, that I use in my project. So I need to use Card component in my project, which needs to be added some styling. So I add style using "styled" from styled-component. After I export my new CardNew and try yo use it in some pages. It works, but when I try to add onMouseLeave/onMouseEnter events to that component, it does not work.

When I try to use Card's initial version from storybook, without any styling and add event, it works.
Here is my code.

```
const CardStyled = styled(Card)`
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  color:red;
  line-height: 1.5em;
`;

export default function CardNew(props) {
  return (
    <CardStyled>
      <Card.Body>
        <p>{props.content}</p>
      </Card.Body>
    </CardStyled`enter code here`>
  )
}
```

And then I use that component and try to handle any event

```
<CardNew onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter()} onMouseLeave={() => onMouseLeave()} >
</CardNew>
```

Can anyone explain why I can't make styling on storybook component, then use it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your CardNew component is not HTML component. So, you should pass all props donw. Like:

```
export default function CardNew(props) {
    return (
        <CardStyled>
        <Card.Body>
            <p {...props}>{props.content}</p>
        </Card.Body>
        </CardStyled`enter code here`>
    )
}
```

This will allow you to handle any event to

element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me. The point is I was trying to find the answer using docs, but no luck. Thanks again

Comment: It's just new ES feature - destruction. No ReactJS specific syntax. Good luck.